# On heroku CLI pg:killall throws an error

Tags: heroku-postgres

I have a hobby postgresql. 
**pg:info** is as below.

```
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           13/20
PG Version:            10.4
Created:               2018-06-15 04:24 UTC
Data Size:             9.0 MB
Tables:                10
Rows:                  1263/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Add-on:
```

When I run **pg:ps**, I get `psql: FATAL:  too many connections for role "xyz"`
Then I try to kill all by **pg:killall** and it throws

```
Terminating connections for all credentials... !
 !    Expected response to be successful, got 500
```

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score -1):

This issue is resolved the next day. Not sure what had happened.